# How to predict using multiple features (X) using predict_proba?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How to predict using multiple features (X) using the predict_proba? I am trying to find the probability of (Balance > 1000) using the following values

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```js
# logistic regression

# import the class
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

feature_cols = ['Income', 'Limit', 'Rating', 'Cards','Age','Education']

X = credit_data[feature_cols] # Features
y = credit_data['Balance_1500'] # Target variable

# instantiate the model (not using the default parameters because it is "crashing" otherwise)
lr = LogisticRegression(max_iter=3000)

# fit the model with data
lr.fit(X, y)

#feature_cols = ['Income', 'Limit', 'Rating', 'Cards','Age','Education']
X_pred1 = ['63','8100','600','4','30','13'].reshape(-1,6)
X_pred2 = ['186','13414','950','4','2','13'].reshape(-1,6)

y_pred = lr.predict_proba(X_pred1)
y_pred = lr.predict_proba(X_pred2)
```

1. I don't know why it is not working. What do I need to modify in the code so that the code can work properly?
2. How could the code get improved so I don't need to create "X_pred1" and "X_pred2"? Ideally, I would like to get the probability for the 2 rows in the "X_pred" variable.

Thanks.

Comment: What is "not working"?  Is there an error message? ... Are you not getting the expected output?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I want to get the probabilities for the 2 rows above. Since predict_proba is giving 2 probabilites per row (the probability of beeing TRUE and the probability of beeing FALSE), i am expecting 4 values since have i have 2 rows. So I am looking looking for the probability of beeing TRUE and the probability of beeing FALSE WHEN i have the following features: Income = 60, Limit = 9000, rating = 600, etc. And the same thing for the second row (of the screenshot I posted above).

Comment: Are your numbers really in quotes, like in `X_pred1`?